# Finding and Printing all Prime numbers from 1 to N

Tags: java

Here is what I have so far, and I am usually pretty good at tracing programs but i just can't figure out where i got stuck. It's supposed to get "N" and Mod it by D, which equals N-1, while D is greater than 1. And once it is done, it goes on the one number less than the original one, and does the same thing while N is greater than 2. And as for the "Count", i just added it so that I could check if the number was prime. Ex: if the count = N-2, which is basically every number from 2 to N-1, then that number is prime.

```
public class Challenge14 {
  public void inti() {
    int count = 0;
    int N = 7;
    int D = N - 1;
    int A = 0;

    while (N > 2) {
      D = N - 1;

      while (D > 1) {
        A = N % D;
        D--;

        if (A == 0) {
          break;
        }

        else {
          count++;
        }
      }

      if (count == N - 2) {
        System.out.println(N);
      }
      N--;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Yeah, i think you need more work here.  Get the algorithm thought out on paper 1st

Comment: I've done that a couple thousand times, but i guess it won't hurt to do it again

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop.

```
for (int i = 1; i<N; i++) {
System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: why not write this as `System.out.println(N);System.out.println(N+1);`?